# Nodejs zlib gunzip "invalid block type" error on Windows but not Mac

Tags: node.js, gzip, zlib

here's my code, I am reading a bunch of file chunks, merging them together, and then gunzipping:

```
const decompress = (buffer) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  zlib.gunzip(buffer, (err, decompressed) => {
    if (err) {return reject(err)}
    resolve(decompressed)
  })
})
const chunkFileNames = fs.readdirSync(chunksFolderPath)
let compressedFile = Buffer.from('')
for (const chunkFileName of chunkFileNames) {
  const chunkFilePath = path.join(chunksFolderPath, chunkFileName)
  const chunk = fs.readFileSync(chunkFilePath)
  compressedFile = Buffer.concat([compressedFile, chunk])
}
const decompressedFile = await decompress(compressedFile) // throws
```

Error is

> Error: invalid block type
> at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:170:17)

I am compressing and chunking the file on linux. When I run the same code on mac/linux it decompresses without error. But when I run the same code on windows I get that error.

What could be the problem? How do I debug this? The chunk files appear to be unchanged when I move the folder to my windows VM, but maybe windows changes them somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the `'binary'` encoding. Problems like this on Windows smell of end-of-line conversions.